# Custom Authorisation in CakePHP 3

Tags: php, authentication, cakephp

I have an intranet app running on IIS, using CakePHP 3. From IIS I am able to access the server var `$_SERVER['AUTH_USER']` and I want to use this variable to authenticate users.

I have created a users table in my database with a username field that I want to match to `AUTH_USER`. I have created a custom Auth component like so:

```
namespace App\Auth;

use Cake\Auth\BaseAuthenticate;
use Cake\Network\Request;
use Cake\Network\Response;
use Cake\ORM\TableRegistry;

class AuthuserAuthenticate extends BaseAuthenticate
{
    public function authenticate(Request $request, Response $response) {
      $username = str_replace('DOMAIN\\', '', $_SERVER['AUTH_USER']);
      $users = TableRegistry::get('Users');
      $user = $users->find()->where(['username' => $username])->first();

      if ($user) {
        return $user;
      } else {
        $user = $this->Users->newEntity();
        $user->username = $username;
        if ($this->Users->save($user)) {
          return $user;
        } else {
          return false;
        }
      }
    }
```

And in the AppController `initialize()` I have tried to load Auth with the custom component.

```
$this->loadComponent('Auth', [
        'authenticate' => [
            'Basic' => [
                'fields' => ['username' => 'username'],
                'userModel' => 'Users'
            ],
        ],
        'loginAction' => [
            'controller' => 'Pages',
            'action' => 'display'
        ],
        'storage' => 'Memory',
        'unauthorizedRedirect' => false
    ]);
    $this->Auth->config('authenticate', 'Authuser');
```

At this point I just get redirected no matter what page I try to go on, I'm not really sure if it's failing to authenticate or something else is the problem.

I have tried adding this to AppController as a test:

```
public function isAuthorized($user)
  {
    return true;
  }
```

But I am unable to access any pages with this code in place. Can anyone let me know what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks,

Kez

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your auth component is not implementing the `authorize` method.

```
public function authorize($user, Request $request) {
  // return true if authorized
  // return false if not authorized
}
```

Secondly, `isAuthorized` is called when using the `ControllerAuthorize` component. If you want to use controller authentication, you should use `ControllerAuthorize` insted.

```
$this->loadComponent('Auth', [
  'authenticate' => 'Controller'
]);
```

*Also: You are configuring the `BasicAuthenticate` component, then immediately overwriting the config.*

Comment: i followed you advice(adding function authorize) but it does not help to set the Auth->user